# How to input a function into GNUoctave?

Tags: function, input, octave, handle

I need to input a function through console into a second one.
I have this function

```
trapez(fun,a,b,n)
```

so if I type this in the command line

```
trapez(@(x) x.^3,0,1,2)
```

it works perfectly but I need to run a program that uses a string input from the user like: 'x^4'and it gets used in the trapez function. I need the 'x^4' to become a function usable for trapez.
I have tried this:

```
t=input('func')
trapez(t,a,b,n)
```

and

```
t=input('func')
str2func(t)
```

but I get this error: error creating function handle "@x.^2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `inline` function:

```
f = inline("x^2");
f(2)
=> 4
```